# Custom query in configureShowFields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

My question is simple, but I don't have a solution.

How can I create my custom query to configureShowFields?

So in configureListFields we have a `createQuery($context = 'list')` function... in similar case I want to create my custom query but in configureShowFields.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this:

i can't found a spicific function to do this, also i create a function showAction in the  Controller like this:

```
public function showAction($id = null) {
    $id = $this->get('request')->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

    $object = $this->admin->getObject($id);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if (!$object) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
    }

    if (false === $this->admin->isGranted('VIEW', $object)) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }
    $user = $em->getRepository('EsolvingEschoolUserBundle:User')->findOneByUserIdByLanguage($object->getId(), $this->getRequest()->getLocale());

    $this->admin->setSubject($object);

    return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('show'), array(
                'action' => 'show',
                'object' => $user,
                'elements' => $this->admin->getShow(),
    ));
}
```

So in my repository i do my custom query, i posted the solution, maybe somebody i help